# python toplevel runs even after root is killed

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I've included some basic code below, which generates a frame, and then a toplevel made to destroy itself. A second is created after the first is destroyed.

When this application is run, while the first toplevel is waiting, if the 'X' on the main window is clicked, it kills itself and the toplevel, but then the second toplevel is created along with a generic Tk(). When that is closed I get an error: `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed`

I've tried using `root.destroy()`, `quit()` and `os._exit()`, but none of these completely stops the application. What can be done to completely stop any script from running after the root window is destroyed?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.L1 = Label(root,text='Hi!')
        self.L1.pack()

 def Window1():
     Wind1 = Toplevel()
     Wind1.geometry('100x100+100+100')
     Wind1.B1 = Button(Wind1,text='Close',command=Wind1.destroy)
     Wind1.B1.pack()
     Wind1.lift(aboveThis=root)
     Wind1.wait_window()

def Window2():
     Wind2 = Toplevel()
     Wind2.geometry('100x100+100+100')
     Wind2.B2 = Button(Wind2,text='Close',command=Wind2.destroy)
     Wind2.B2.pack()
     Wind2.lift(aboveThis=root)
     Wind2.wait_window()

def Close_Window():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+50+50')
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',Close_Window)
app = Application(root)
Window1()
Window2()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see a few problems here. First off you are not telling the `Toplevel()` window what their parent window is. They need to be like this `Wind1 = Toplevel(root)`. Second your code that says `wait_window()` is what is causing this behavior. When you call `Window1()` The program is waiting it seams for the window to be closed before moving onto the next command. I think this code needs some rework. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In a more detailed application that I am writing, I'm creating the `Toplevel()` with an entry form for the user to enter data, which will be used on the main window. I've got the `wait_window()` in place to prevent the second `Toplevel()` from being run at the same time as the first. I'm just trying to cover all of the bases of situations where the application can be shut down by the user.

Comment: I have added a 2nd example in my code to give you a cleaner more reliable Class to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason for your error is caused by 2 problems. One is that both windows are not being created at start up due to the `wait_window()` method. The other problem is the lack of a parent being defined for your `Toplevel()` windows.

Take a look at the below modified code. (Note this code needs some work still but is what you need to change to fix the error)

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.L1 = Label(root, text='Hi!')
        self.L1.pack()

def Window1():
    Wind1 = Toplevel(root)
    Wind1.geometry('100x100+100+100')
    Wind1.B1 = Button(Wind1,text='Close',command=Wind1.destroy)
    Wind1.B1.pack()
    Wind1.lift(aboveThis=root)
    #Wind1.wait_window()

def Window2():
    Wind2 = Toplevel(root)
    Wind2.geometry('100x100+100+100')
    Wind2.B2 = Button(Wind2,text='Close',command=Wind2.destroy)
    Wind2.B2.pack()
    Wind2.lift(aboveThis=root)
    #Wind2.wait_window()

def Close_Window():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+50+50')
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',Close_Window)
app = Application(root)
Window1()
Window2()
root.mainloop()
```

I think you would benifit more from moving everything into a class. This way you can use class attributes to manage all data within the application including those you get from `Toplevel()` widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('100x100+50+50')
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_window)
        self.L1 = tk.Label(self, text='Hi!')
        self.L1.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Window 1", command=self.window1).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Window 2", command=self.window2).pack()

    def window1(self):
        wind1 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        wind1.geometry('100x100+100+100')
        wind1.B1 = tk.Button(wind1, text='Close', command=wind1.destroy).pack()

    def window2(self):
        wind2 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        wind2.geometry('100x100+100+100')
        wind2.B2 = tk.Button(wind2, text='Close', command=wind2.destroy).pack()

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()


app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```